# Contacts and text messages merging after 13.1 iPhone update

Tags: messages, contacts, ios

My boyfriend has an android for his personal use and an iPhone for work. I updated my iPhone to 13.1 and now both of his phones are combined in my text messages. I hate it! How do I fix this problem?